# Raspberry Pi Security Camera and Twilio

Tags: pi-3, opencv

So I am working on a 4G enabled security camera. While I know there is several options to choose from I was kind of intrigued by the Twilio Security Camera Blueprint, https://www.twilio.com/wireless/blueprints/security-camera/, as an option for what I am trying to do. So I purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 +, Sixfab LTE Hat, and began the setup. As of now, everything appears to be working LTE side but the dang Twilio stuff isn't working.

First, off they haven't updated their walkthrough but changed some files around so after some research and several hours I was finally able to add the camera to "the front end" (page 3 of the walkthrough) and then started the config on my pi.

As I went through the steps on the Raspberry Pi I was able to successfully do everything EXCEPT issue the NPM start command.

Every time I issue the command it fails to start and gives me the following error. I reached out to Twilio Support to see if they had any suggestions but all they could say was to make sure I completed all steps in the guide.

Based on the last few hours I've spent on this I am guessing that OPENCV no longer has a function called ImageSimilarity and they don't exactly say what they changed it to. Does anybody have any ideas? I'm beginning to think Twilio might not be the best option if it is this difficult to setup or even build upon. Below is the printout of running the command as well as the npm debug log.

NPM Start Command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/camera $ npm start

> wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start /home/pi/camera
> node security-camera.js

Got configuration for camera: Camera1
Control map: 
Snapshot document: 
Starting camera capture
calling....
/opt/vc/bin/raspistill --width 640 --height 360 --output /home/pi/camera/images/camera%03d.jpg --nopreview --timeout 1800000 --timelapse 250 --quality 80 --rotation 180 --thumb 0:0:0
raspicam::watcher::event rename
raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event rename
raspicam::watcher::event rename
Frame captured: null 1579100567771 camera000.jpg
CV loaded: /home/pi/camera/images/camera000.jpg [ Matrix 360x640 ]
raspicam::watcher::event rename
stderr: mmal: Skipping frame 1 to restart at frame 2

raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event change
raspicam::watcher::event rename
raspicam::watcher::event rename
Frame captured: null 1579100568502 camera002.jpg
CV loaded: /home/pi/camera/images/camera002.jpg [ Matrix 360x640 ]
/home/pi/camera/security-camera.js:115
        CV.ImageSimilarity(im, previousImage, function (err, dissimilarity) {
           ^

TypeError: CV.ImageSimilarity is not a function
    at CV.readImage (/home/pi/camera/security-camera.js:115:12)
    at RaspiCam.<anonymous> (/home/pi/camera/security-camera.js:112:8)
    at emitThree (events.js:136:13)
    at RaspiCam.emit (events.js:217:7)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/pi/camera/node_modules/raspicam/lib/raspicam.js:196:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1364:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start: `node security-camera.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-01-15T15_02_50_331Z-debug.log
pi@raspberrypi:~/camera $
```

NPM Debug Log

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node',
    1 verbose cli   '/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/npm',
    1 verbose cli   'start' ]
    2 info using npm@6.13.6
    3 info using node@v8.17.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
    5 info lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~prestart: wireless-security-camera@0.0.1
    6 info lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: wireless-security-camera@0.0.1
    7 verbose lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: PATH: /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm$
    9 verbose lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: CWD: /home/pi/camera
    10 silly lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node security-camera.js' ]
    11 silly lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle wireless-security-camera@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
    13 verbose stack Error: wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start: `node security-camera.js`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/$
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/$
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
    14 verbose pkgid wireless-security-camera@0.0.1
    15 verbose cwd /home/pi/camera
    16 verbose Linux 4.19.75-v7+
    17 verbose argv "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node" "/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/npm" "start"
    18 verbose node v8.17.0
    19 verbose npm  v6.13.6
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start: `node security-camera.js`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 start script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

NPM Package List

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/camera $ npm list --depth 0
wireless-security-camera@0.0.1 /home/pi/camera
nyc@15.0.0
opencv@6.2.0
raspicam@0.2.14
request@2.88.0
twilio-common@0.1.7
twilio-sync@0.11.5
uuid@3.3.3
```

Comment: A smal [help](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/272)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: Thanks Ingo I have edited the post to have the logs as text vs the picture.

Comment: OpenCV installed version  ?

Comment: @Ephemeral 

opencv@6.2.0

Comment: @NicholasMcNel, I really have small eyes sorry.

Comment: @NicholasMcNel, Have you try to follow [this](https://github.com/twilio/wireless-security-camera/tree/master/pi) ?

Comment: @Ephemeral Yes I have tried following that as well as the link i first mentioned above. The error is happening when running the NPM Start Command as mentioned at the bottom of you referenced link. I know that Twilio hasn't updated the git for sometime and I even had to do some research to find out what they changed because a couple steps were not accurate

Comment: @NicholasMcNel, The declaration is [here](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/585790f06e5667e52c7add413748621c2592e2c7/src/Features2d.cc)

Comment: @NicholasMcNel : You have [here](https://github.com/twilio/wireless-security-camera/blob/master/pi/package.json) : `"dependencies": {
    "opencv": "^6.0.0",` ... Maybe try to install `node-opencv` ?

Comment: @Ephemeral Ill give it a try again, I want to say last night i tried to install the node-opencv as outlined on his git page "npm i opencv" and it installs what is currently installed on the machine.

Comment: @NicholasMcNel, oh yes, I was actually looking for if npm i opencv install the github repository (5 years old). 
I don't see a solution now.

Comment: @NicholasMcNel, Also this function seems to be asynchronous, I can see in your log : `stderr: mmal: Skipping frame 1 to restart at frame 2` ... maybe raspistill is too slow.

Comment: I know this is off-topic, and perhaps even inappropriate, but I can't help myself.  I was struck by the response `Twilio Support` gave to the OP: All they had to offer was "RTFM"! Is anyone else struck by the fact that this forum is covering for `Twilio` - a profit-making enterprise? ... guess that's why we're so richly rewarded :)  OTOH, maybe `Twilio` has cut tech support to cover the salary of their new [**Social Impact Officer**](https://is.gd/BOH1lF) :P

Comment: @Seamus I won't lie your comment made me laugh just alittle. I have been working with Twilio still in regards to this issue and its honestly horrible. I originally sent an email to them first thing two days ago, followed up with a phone call yesterday, and then finally received a response to my original email and the response basically said "Unless you pay for support the response time is "first come first serve" to give an idea I sent an email at 4:30PM MST yesterday in reply to their email and received a response at 10:00AM MST today. They are slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not exactly an answer I have figured out the issue. After doing a lot more research i found that the twilio blueprint example i was following was using the OpenCV 2 as the basis for the functions. The only way now to proceed would be to rebuild the script with OpenCV 4 functionality.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.